# How can I optimize my MySQL query? as it is taking 45 seconds to fetch records

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

My database table "ringtune_history" has 40K records and "ringtunes" has 4K records and the query is taking too much time to process.

```
SELECT  `ringtunes`.*,
        count(case when ringtune_history.Action = 'Download' then ringtune_history.Action end) as Org_Downloads,
        count(case when ringtune_history.Action = 'View' then ringtune_history.Action end) as Org_Views,
        count(case when ringtune_history.Action = 'Play' then ringtune_history.Action end) as Total_Plays,
        count(case when ringtune_history.Action = 'Like' then ringtune_history.Action end) as Total_Likes,
        `categories`.`Name` as `Category_Name`
    FROM  `ringtunes`
    LEFT JOIN  `ringtune_history`  ON `ringtune_history`.`Ringtune_Id` = `ringtunes`.`Id`
    LEFT JOIN  `categories`  ON `categories`.`Id` = `ringtunes`.`Category`
    WHERE  `ringtunes`.`Deleted` = 0
      AND  `ringtunes`.`Status` = 1
      AND  `categories`.`Deleted` = 0
      AND  `categories`.`Status` = 1
    GROUP BY  `ringtunes`.`Id`
    ORDER BY  `ringtunes`.`Id` DESC
    LIMIT  20
```

Comment: You need to add indexes on your  table, create an index on all the tables. To create indexes, use columns which you are specifying in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Very helpful, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fine! It's the table itself that is the issue.

Be sure to add indexes to the columns that you use to find records with (eg. `ringtunes.Deleted = 0`, your index will need to go on the Deleted column). Same goes for the other columns that you check for values.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `LEFT` unless you need NULLs where the 'right' table is missing.  Clearly `categories` does not need to be `LEFT`.  It is unclear whether `ringtune_history` could be changed to a plain `JOIN`.

Indexes needed:

```
ringtune:  (deleted, status, ID) or (status, deleted, ID)
ringtune_history:  (Ringtune_Id, Action)
```

(Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` in case there are other clues/tips.)

You seem to have the "explode-implode" pattern -- First you `JOIN` some tables, thereby leading to a potentially larger set of intermediate rows.  In doing so, that table is quite bulky due to lots of columns.  Then you collapse things with a `GROUP BY`.  If possible *first* find the *ids* of the table that you eventually `GROUP BY`.  Then `JOIN` that to the other tables and (probably) back to the original table -- in order to get the rest of the columns.

You can at least postpone looking at `ringtune_history` until after you have located the 20 desired rows in the other two tables.  This will limit the lookups in it to only 20, not "all".

If `deleted` and `status` of the two columns always match, then don't check them in `categories`.  (This will make the explode-implode fix easier to achieve.)  If they are necessarily independent, then I suggest that each table might be better off if you actually deleted the undesirable rows (or moved them to an archive table).  The current `WHERE` clause is complex since it filters on two different tables.

(Not critical:)  This

```
count(case when ringtune_history.Action = 'View' then ringtune_history.Action end)
```

can be shortened to

```
SUM(ringtune_history.Action = 'View')
```